# PHP MYSQL how to check amount is DR or CR?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created the balance sheet system using PHP MYSQLi. Where admin can manage clients account information

I am using column `action_type` when inserting data.

Below is my table structure.

[image]

I have tried below code for getting DR and CR:

```
<?php
$list_balance = mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT * FROM tbl_balancesheet where client_id='".$_REQUEST['clientID']."' AND YEAR(created_date) = '".$_REQUEST['id']."' ORDER by id asc" );
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($list_balance);
    $total = 0;
    $totalAmount = 0;
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_balance)){
        $totalAmount += $row['amount']; 
        
        if($row['action_type']=='dr'){
            $debit = $row['amount'];
            $total += $row['amount'];
        }else{
            $credit = $row['amount'];
            $total -= $row['amount']; 
        }
        
        if($totalAmount < $total){
            $checkAmount = 'dr';
        }else{
            $checkAmount = 'cr';
        }
        
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="5%">
        <a href='edit_particular.php?auth=<?php echo $salt_key_check.'&cid='.$row['id']; ?>' role='button' title='Edit' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a>
          <a href='delete_particular.php?auth=<?php echo $salt_key_check.'&cid='.$row['id'];?>&client_id=<?php echo $row['client_id'] ?>&lid=<?php echo $row['area_id']; ?>' role='button' title='Delete' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>   
        </td>
        <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['created_date'])); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['particular']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if($row['action_type']=='dr'){ 
                    echo $debit;
                }else{
                    echo '';        
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
                if($row['action_type']=='cr'){ 
                    echo $credit;
                }else{
                    echo '';        
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php if ($i < $numRows)
            {
        ?><?php echo $total; ?>&nbsp;<small><?php //echo $row['action_type']; ?></small>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <strong><?php echo $total; ?></strong>&nbsp;<small><?php echo $checkAmount; ?></small>
        <?php } ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $i++; }  
?>
```

Below is an expected result:

[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: What is not currently working, exactly?

Comment: If you can see the result screenshot, I want to check amount is dr or cr. I want to display dr or cr in the last row.

Comment: Yes, I see what you want - but I don't see what you *have*. So I'll ask again - what exactly is not working for your right now?

Comment: Right now I am doing the sum of total `amount` and differencing from the last row `total` `if($totalAmount < $total){
   $checkAmount = 'dr';
  }else{
   $checkAmount = 'cr';
  }`. But it's showing every time `cr` only.

Comment: Well then `$totalAmount < $total` is simply not true, so make debug outputs to _check_ what these two variables contain …

Comment: @04FS I have debugged this condition, but it's not working.

Comment: That statement is almost completely void of any useful information. Explain what exactly you did and what the result was _properly_.

Comment: @04FS First, I get a complete `SUM` of the column amount. And then compare to the last row result in `$total`. `if($totalAmount < $total)`, but it's always returning `false`. I want to get if admin is asking any amount from a client then it would be `DR`, but if the client is asking amount from admin then it would be `CR`.

Comment: Did you or did you not make debug outputs by now to check what those two variables actually contain at this point?

Comment: @04FS Yes, I did now the result is `$totalAmount = 110000` and the last row `$total = 40000`. It means this should be `CR`, it's correct but another client has `$totalAmount = 75000` and the last row `$total = 5000`. It means this should be `DR`, but it's showing `CR`

Comment: And where _exactly_ did you make those debug outputs? You are checking the condition while the loop is still running, in each iteration. Might make more sense to do that directly in the place where you want to output cr/dr, inside that last table cell. Try and replace `<?php echo $checkAmount; ?>` with `<?php echo $totalAmount < $total ? 'dr' : 'cr'; ?>` and see if you get a different result then.

Comment: @04FS  Thanks I has tried but not getting the expected result.

Comment: If you can’t manage to answer the questions you are asked for clarification, then I’m out.

Comment: When you said `Below is an expected result:`, is that mean that is what you are getting now? Or that is what you want to get but not getting it?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that, the result you've posted is the one you are getting now; and your issue is only the last row shows CR and other rows does not show CR/DR text.

Why don't you try to invert your `if` condition.

```
if ($i < $numRows)
```

To

```
if ($i >= $numRows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This `if($totalAmount < $total){` is *always false*. Why? Because this `$totalAmount += $row['amount'];` is constantly increasing because `amount` is always a positive number. Even if all transactions are DR; in that case `$totalAmount == $total`.

Do you need `$totalAmount` at all?. If `$total < 0` then `$checkAmount = 'cr'`, full stop.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it at my end using below query out of while loop:

```
$sqlDRCR = mysqli_query($con_db,"SELECT id,area_id,client_id, 
                   IF(Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                     WHEN action_type = 'dr' THEN amount 
                                   end, 0)) - Sum(Coalesce(CASE 
                                                             WHEN action_type = 'cr' THEN 
                                                             amount 
                                                           end, 0)) > 0, 'dr', 'cr') AS balance 
            FROM tbl_balancesheet WHERE `client_id` = '".$_GET['cid']."'");
            $resDRCR = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlDRCR);
```

Comment: I think you accidentally forgot to explain your solution (and clarify your question).  ...and to use secure coding practices like prepared statements.